# blank iframe using WebBrowser control on Compact Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iframe, compact-framework, smart-device-framework

I'm Creating a Smart Device Proyect un Visual Studio 2008, I'm using a WebBrowser Control to show a Web Site. The problem is when i set the SRC to an Iframe, basically the iframe don't show the requested Page, this appears in Blank, it only happens on WebBrowser Control, if i navigate to WebSite using Internet Explorer on Device, works fine...

I'm setting the src like this:

```
    `document.getElementById("IframeId").src="WebPageRequested.jsp";`
```

Any help?

(Sorry For my English)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile has a stripped down version of IE4.

Create a basic HTML page with a simple IFRAME saying, "Hello World!".

Put that on a website (public or internal).

If your Windows Mobile device can display the "Hello World!" text, you can move forward with further development.

If not, the stripped down version of IE4 does not support IFRAME.